# Could Android Studio and Intellij IDEA Ultimate be installed on the same computer?

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I would like to learn to develop Android apps and I need your advice before broke my current installation.

I have IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 15 installed on my computer (Ubuntu 15). Well, I have some doubts:

1. <del>Is IntelliJ IDEA + Android plugin the same as Android Studio?</del>
2. If they are different, can I install both in the same computer?
3. <del>Could a project created on IntelliJ be opened on Android Studio, and vice versa?</del>

TIA,

**Edit:** The questions 1 and 3 were solved thanks to the yUdoDis' comment. Their projects are compatible, and although they are practically the same, they have some differences that could be important.

Comment: I used Droidio (Android Studio) quite a bit a year or so back, and liked it quite a bit. Since it's made specifically for Android development by the Droidians themselves, it seems a good bet.

Comment: all of your queries can be answered from 
http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2013/05/intellij-idea-and-android-studio-faq/
:)..
My opinion, stick to android studio for android development as it is tailor made for android development especially with the gradle support.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. However, if they are the same, could they be installed on the same computer without conflicts?

Comment: Yes, i've installed both without any problem

Comment: But for android I only use AS :)

Comment: yes you can install both and their projects should be compatible as they follow the same project structure.
PS:@MarioSotil thanks for the mention (:

Comment: I have both IJ IDEA Ultimate and AS installed. They are different applications/programs so there is no issue in having both installed.

Comment: Yes you can, (for 2)

Answer (score 1):

Android Studio and IDEA Ultimate (IU)/Community are not the same. AS is based on the Intellij Platform, but they are different.

That means:

- There are plugins for AS that do not run on IU (like JRebel for Android) and vice versa.
- You can of course install both IDEs on your system. They have different folders for storing their data.
- IU + Android Plugin is not the same as Android Studio. They have different release plans. So the features are not automatically in sync.